# How can I search for a class among all .css files in Developer Tools?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, ie-developer-tools

I am trying to find a CSS class definiton on the loaded page by using the Developer Tools of IE.

When I use the search box under CSS tab it seems it only searches the selected CSS file.

Is it possible to perform a search among all css files loaded by the page?

Comment: Do you have to use IE & Developer Tools? Firebug's search box does exactly what you want.

Comment: So, you say no possibility for that in Developer Tools of IE?

Comment: I don't know, and I don't have IE installed here to check (if I could say so definitively I'd have posted an answer instead of a comment). All I can say is that Firebug does what you're asking. If you *need* to use IE for whatever reason then I can't be of any help; but if you can switch to a different browser, I'd say do it, because they all have better debugging tools than IE.

Comment: @pencilCake If you have 10 stylesheets you will have to go trough the pain to switch manually from the dropdown each time. The option "search all" is not in.

Comment: Then I wonder why they could not consider to introduce such a useful feature to Interent Explorer Developer Tools :(

Comment: @pencilCake You should uninstall IE.. Please. Atleast thats what the majority of users on SO think. Not me

Answer (score 0):

Ok I tried and couldn't do what you're asking for with IE's developer toolbar. as @Spudley said though, Firebug does it.

Answer (score -2):

We ran into a similar issue with our WordPress sites (i.e. not being able to search all CSS/PHP/JS files at once). As a solve, we created a plugin to allow us to do just that. If this question is related to a WordPress site, the plugin might help - rather than searching in Firebug and then having to jump back onto WordPress, you can search all and edit directly in WordPress. Plugin is called [WP Backend File Search](https://www.wpbackendfilesearch.com/)

Comment: OP was asking for a general client-side solution, not a WordPress specific server-side one.